# Using different Ordering for Sets

Tags: haskell

I was reading a Chapter 2 of Purely Functional Data Structures, which talks about unordered sets implemented as binary search trees. The code is written in ML, and ends up showing a `signature ORDERED` and a `functor UnbalancedSet(Element: ORDERED): SET`. Coming from more of a C++ background, this makes sense to me; custom comparison function objects form part of the type and can be passed in at construction time, and this seems fairly analogous to the ML functor way of doing things.

When it comes to Haskell, it seems the behavior depends only on the `Ord` instance, so if I wanted to have a set that had its order reversed, it seems like I'd have to use a `newtype` instance, e.g.

```
newtype ReverseInt = ReverseInt Int deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Ord ReverseInt where
    compare (ReverseInt a) (ReverseInt b)  
        | a == b = EQ
        | a < b  = GT
        | a > b  = LT
```

which I could then use in a set:

```
let x = Set.fromList $ map ReverseInt [1..5]
```

Is there any better way of doing this sort of thing that doesn't resort to using `newtype` to create a different `Ord` instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is really the way to go. Yes, having a `newtype` is sometimes annoying but you get some big benefits:

- When you see a `Set a` and you know `a`, you immediately know what type of comparison it uses (sort of the same way that purity makes code more readable by not making you have to trace execution). You don't have to know where that `Set a` comes from.
- For many cases, you can [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce) your way through multiple newtypes at once. For example, I can turn `xs = [1,2,3] :: Int` into `ys = [ReverseInt 1, ReverseInt 2, ReverseInt 3] :: [ReverseInt]` just using `ys = coerce xs :: [ReverseInt]`. Unfortunately, that isn't the case for `Set` (and it shouldn't - you'd need the coercion function to be monotonic to not screw up the data structure invariants, and there is not yet a way to express that in the type system).
- `newtype`s end up being more composable than you expect. For example, the `ReverseInt` type you made already exists in a form that generalizes to reversing *any* type with an `Ord` constraint: it is called [`Down`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Down). To be explicit, you could use `Down Int` instead of `ReversedInt`, and you get the instance you wrote out for free!

Of course, if you still feel very strongly about this, nothing is stopping you from writing your version of `Set` which has to have a field which is the comparison function it uses. Something like

```
data Set a = Set { comparisionKey :: a -> a -> Ordering
                 , ...
                 }
```

Then, every time you make a `Set`, you would have to pass in the comparison key.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info about `coerce` and `Down`, that's very helpful.

Comment: Indeed, `coerce` is really great for this kind of wrappers.

Comment: If I was rolling my own set parameterized by the comparison function, I'd want to have it tied to a **type** parameter, not just a field. Otherwise you can't e.g. rule out unioning sets with different comparisons (probably end up reinserting everything from the right set using the left order, losing commuativity and maybe some tree graft optimizations). Probably I'd just add a type parameter for a newtype to transparently wrap/unwrap and use the existing Set for everything under the hood.

Comment: @Ben Yeah, that was the point I was trying to get at in my first bullet. You somehow want to have that universality property, otherwise all hell breaks lose. (Or at least name the instances as Idris does)

Comment: @Ben That's a very good point. Until now I never realized that e.g. Java `TreeSet` has no "set-specific" intersection method, only one taking a generic `Collection`. Indeed, Java can not assume the comparator is the same for two sets of the same type. This might lead to a less efficient algorithm -- Haskell `Data.Set` guarantees O(m*log(nm + 1)) where m is the smaller set size.